# How to limit object creation to methods of specific class?

Tags: c#

Is it possible to limit object creation to methods of specific class?

For exemple: I have a class Transaction, and I would like to limit it object creation to methods of any class that inherits from AbstractService or IService:

**Allowed Scenario:**

```
public class ServiceA : AbstractService (or IService)
{
    public void MethodA() 
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction();
    }

    public void MethodB() 
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction();
    }
}
```

**Prohibited Scenario:**

```
public class ServiceB
{
    public void MethodA() 
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction(); // cannot create
    }

    public void MethodB() 
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction(); // cannot create
    }
}
```

There is a access modifier or something else that I can mount that scenarios?

Comment: If `ServiceA` is in the same assembly as `Transaction` but in a separate assembly than `ServiceB`, you can make the constructor for `Transaction` `internal`.  Otherwise, you could make it `private` and use reflection to create an instance of it and prohibit other classes from creating instances by throwing an exception.  I think that's the best you can do.

Comment: Can't think of an elegant way how this should be implemented. A dirty hack might indeed be to check the `StackFrame` in `Transaction`'s constructor. But actually I think you have a wrong design decision here, but I can't decide that without knowing what you are _actually_ trying to achieve. Why you want to do that? And would it be legal if `ServiceA.MethodA()` would call `ServiceB.MethodA` which then creates the `Transaction`? Or only "direct" calls from `ServiceA`? Whatever "direct" means after compiler optimization.

Comment: The keyword `protected` could help you, it depends on how Transaction is declared.

Comment: The problem is is that Transaction cant know whats calling it using the methods shown above..  as in essense the same transaction is being made in all 4 calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There is a access modifier or something else that I can mount that scenarios?

Yes there is *something else* that can "mount" that scenario, but it's a lot of work and abstraction for, in my opinion, very little reward.  This requires returning an interface of the Transaction, not a concrete type.  (I'm pretty sure this works, I haven't compiled it however).

```
public abstract class AbstractService 
{
}

public interface IService
{
}

public interface ITransaction
{
}


public static class TransactionFactory 
{
    // created them as extensions, but you could remove *this*
    public static ITransaction CreateTransaction(this AbstractService instance)
    {
        return new Transaction ();
    }

    public static ITransaction CreateTransaction(this IService instance)
    {
        return new Transaction ();
    }

    private class Transaction : ITransaction
    {
        public Transaction ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

As a side note, someone technically could pass in *null*, so it would be best to do additional checking of the method parameters (however, that would be a runtime issue instead of a compile time issue).

If you wanted compile time checking I think you could do...

```
public interface ITransactionFactory { }

public abstract class AbstractService : ITransactionFactory { }

public interface IService  : ITransactionFactory { }

public static class TransactionFactory<T>
  where T : ITransactionFactory
{
  public static ITransaction CreateTransaction(this T instance)
    {
        return new Transaction ();
    }
    // ....
```

Not quite sure if the second one works

Comment: At least call the factory methods `CreateTransaction`, otherwise it looks like youre creating a service (`var transaction = myServiceInstance.Create()` looks weird)

Comment: I guess it depends on if it's used as an ExtensionMethod or not.. but I agree.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, there is no access modifier which says "This object can only be constructed from a class which implements a specific interface".

You could code your way round this limitation, but its far from clean/foolproof.

```
public class Transaction
{
    private Transaction(){} // private important!

    public static Transaction Create(object creator)
    {
        if(creator is IService)
            return new Transaction();

        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

public class ServiceA : IService
{
    public void MethodA() 
    {
        var transaction = Transaction.Create(this);  // works
    }
}


public class ServiceB
{
    public void MethodA() 
    {
        var transaction = Transaction.Create(this);  // fails
    }
}
```

It should be obvious how easily circumventable the above is. I suspect you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you *think* this was the way to solve it.

Comment: Definitely an XY Problem.

Comment: The problem of it solution is that: Imagine a class Controller, if I create a Service inside any method of it, and pass the service created to a Transaction inside the same method, I can. But I want that be prohibited as well, because transaction could only be created inside methods of a specific service (that is limited by inherited class, interface or other way).

Comment: @ErikPhilips I agree, sometimes its helpful to show just how bad your code will need to be in order to solve the problem you think you have!

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni Im not sure I understand - are you trying to stop programmers making bad design decisions with a coded solution? There are tools for that like fxCop.

Comment: @Jamiec exactly that!

Comment: @ViniciusOttoni Controlling programmers makes herding cats look easy. You're better off trying to educate than code blockers for them. As I mentioned there are plenty of tools to review code and tell programmers where they mightve gone wrong.

Comment: @Jamiec I know that could be strange, but in my scenario, educate programmers, 
unfortunately is not a option. I have to search a "radical way".

Comment: The .NET framework employs all sorts of tricks for herding cats, er, programmers, away from doing things they shouldn't. The reference source is wonderfully educational for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to do, but it seems like this should do the trick:

```
public abstract class AbstractService : IService
{
    protected class Transaction
    {

    }
}

public class ServiceA : AbstractService
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction();
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction();
    }
}

public class ServiceB
{
    public void MethodA()
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction(); // cannot create
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        var transaction = new Transaction(); // cannot create
    }
}

internal interface IService
{
}
```

If you want anyone else to be able to use the `Transaction`, you'll need to have it implement some public interface or inherit it from another public class, but you can now ensure that no one else can create a Transaction object.

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: I does not allow objects derived from an interface to create a transaction.

Comment: What does "derived from an interface" mean? If AbstractService declares as implementing the IService interface, that effectively gets him what he wants because every child service will likewise have to implement IService. He could also declare IService as internal which would prevent any external users from implementing their own IService.